# Determine URLs from my site that where shared by current user friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've got a PHP article site that allows logging in with Facebook and I need to show a list of "articles shared by your friends". Every article is shared as a link like mysite.com/articles/1.

I've seen [this](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7048339/facebook-api-all-links-shared-by-all-friends) question but as the url field in the link table is not indexed, I can't use "WHERE url LIKE '%mysite.com%'" and therefore the retrieved list of links will be too big to filter through a PHP loop (100 users sharing 100 each will show 10000 urls to filter on every page load).

I'm currently using this FQL query: "SELECT url FROM link WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()) LIMIT 1000;" and recursively executing it if not enough records remain after the filter. Also, for some reason this query is taking much longer than others.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can consider offline (such as using a cronjob) to periodically fetch results from facebook,
and stored result locally (such as mysql)

once you have the result locally,

- you don't have to wait for FQL
- you can prepare your own way of cache warming (suc has memcache)
- you can group the result accordingly (such as by category, tag ... etc)
- you don't have to calculate in real-time, every thing can be get from cache

Comment: Yeah, thought about it, but it's still not the cleanest solution and it's not real time. In the meantime I'm storing a row-per-share to calculate it and getting rid of FQL, but this of course leaves out copy-paste shares. Thanks anyway!